# Side nav won't open with template reference variable

Tags: angular, angular-material

OK. This is stumping me. The `md-sidenav` is being referenced by `#sidenav` in the following template.  However it does nothing.

```
<md-toolbar color="primary">
     <button type="button" md-button (click)="sidenav.open()">
      Open sidenav
    </button>
</md-toolbar>

<md-sidenav-container>
  <md-sidenav #sidenav class="example-sidenav">
    Jolly good!
  </md-sidenav>
</md-sidenav-container>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/M8cJTqPKwZwz8UP3dod9?p=preview

Interestingly, placing a second button within the `md-sidenav-container` makes both work.

The docs say that you should be able to reference a template variable from anywhere in the template.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably facing an issue where the sidenav IS opening, but because you haven't properly set the height of the sidenav container, you aren't seeing the effect.

Try using some css to set the height of the sidenav container. Something like:

```
 html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
 }

 md-sidenav-container {
    flex: 1;
 }

 md-sidenav {
    width: 240px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the toolbar in the container.

```
    <md-sidenav-container>
      <md-toolbar color="primary">
        <button *ngIf="!sidenav.opened" type="button" md-button (click)="sidenav.open()">
          Open
        </button>
        <button *ngIf="sidenav.opened" type="button" md-button (click)="sidenav.close()">
          Close
        </button>
      </md-toolbar>
      <md-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" class="example-sidenav">
        Jolly good!
      </md-sidenav>
      testing
   </md-sidenav-container>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/MIbzRuM4oUHZZKUZdu30?p=preview.